# Run Spring Service From console

Tags: java, spring-mvc, console

Is there any way to run spring service from console,like running a basic java program.
I need to change some data in production database by running a java program.for one time purpose.I have to use some pojo files and some other services. i don't want to run it with using server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps. Create simple spring boot project without any web dependency and implement CommandLineRunner component e.g.

```
@Component
public class CommandLineAppStartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final MyService service;

    public CommandLineAppStartupRunner(MyService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        service.doWork();
    }
}
```

create executable jar (e.g. `mvn package` if you use maven) and then you can simply run it (`java -jar myapp.jar`)